# Problemas com fwrite em arquivo binário

Tags: c, arquivo, int, binary

Estou tentando fazer escrita e leitura de um inteiro em arquivo binário com o seguinte código:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>

typedef struct{
    int free_slot;
}header;

void main(void){
    FILE *fd = fopen("test.dad","a+b");
    fseek(fd,0,SEEK_SET);

    header aux_header;

    fread(&aux_header, sizeof(header),1,fd);
    printf("Header: %d\n", aux_header.free_slot);
    scanf("%d",&aux_header.free_slot);

    fseek(fd,0,SEEK_SET);
    if(fwrite(&aux_header,sizeof(header),1,fd) != 1)
        puts("Write Error");

    fclose(fd);
}
```

Estou rodando várias vezes este programa, mas depois da primeira escrita, as próximas são ignoradas e não vão para o arquivo.

Comment: Em C, enquanto não deres o flush no arquivo ou fechares o mesmo, o que está armazenado no buffer não é passado para o arquivo de fato. Te aconselho a abrir o arquivo para leitura, usá-lo e fechá-lo. E quando quiser escrever no mesmo, faça o mesmo procedimento.

Comment: Mesmo assim não funcionou, tentei abrir (a+b)->escrever->fechar->abrir para leitura (rb)->ler->fechar, mas o problema continua, depois de escrever o primeiro número com sucesso, os demais não o sobrescrevem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Encontrei uma solução para o problema. Usando o modo r+b o algoritmo funciona (estava utilizando a+b para criar um arquivo caso ele não existisse, mas por algum motivo este modo não está funcionando na minha aplicação).

Answer (score 2):

Em C, enquanto não deres o flush no arquivo ou fechares o mesmo, o que está armazenado no buffer não é passado para o arquivo de fato. Te aconselho a abrir o arquivo para leitura, usá-lo e fechá-lo. E quando quiser escrever no mesmo, faça o mesmo procedimento.

Segue o código que usei para teste:

```
typedef struct{
    int free_slot;
}header;

int main(){
    FILE *fd = fopen("test.bin","ab");
    header aux_header;

    scanf("%d",&aux_header.free_slot);
    fwrite(&aux_header,sizeof(header),1,fd);
    aux_header.free_slot = 2; 
    fwrite(&aux_header,sizeof(header),1,fd);
    fclose(fd); 

    fd = fopen("test.bin","rb");
    rewind(fd); 
    while (!feof(fd)) { 
        fread(&aux_header, sizeof(header),1,fd); 
        printf("Header: %d\n", aux_header.free_slot); 
    }
    fclose(fd); 
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta, Rafael, mas ainda não é o que eu procuro. O que eu quero é sobrescrever a primeira posição. Não sei porquê, mas eu tentei usar o rewind antes de escrever (usando seu código) mas sempre a escrita ocorre no final, por que?

Comment: Agora entendi o que queres. Podes usar a função fseek para se movimentar que nem estavas usando e a função ftell para descobrir a posição atual (ele retorna um long e este long pode ser usado como parâmetro de entrada da função fseek).

Comment: O problema é que, mesmo usando fseek para retornar (e conferindo com ftell que estou no início do arquivo), a escrita ocorre no final do arquivo quando dou fwrite. Não estou conseguindo sobrescrever as primeiras posições do arquivo.